# Bilinear interpolation of 2d data using c / awk / shell

Tags: c++, c, shell, awk

Does anyone know bilinear interpolation of data using any of these language c / awk /shell / c++

My data file, this file is not sorted don't know how to do :( very big file

```
 row col data 
 20 14 91 
 21 15 95
 21 14 162 
 20 15 210
```

I expect ouput like this 0.5 interval for column  and 0.2 for row

```
 20 14 91 
 20 14.5 150.5
 20 15 210
 20.2 14.5 146.1
 .....
 .....
 .....
 21 14 162
 21 14.5 128.5
 21 15 95
```

Please help

Comment: Where do the extra `data` come from, like `150.5`? This is very unclear.

Comment: Dear Jotne its very clear that you don't know what is bilinear interpolation, thank you so much for negative voting..

Comment: I did not give you negative vote, that you should blame other.

Comment: Sorry Jotne then, I am short temper..forgive me..

Comment: Are the starting row and col values of 20 and 14 significant, or does your "very big file" actually start on (0,0)? Are all rows and columns used, or is this some sort of sparse array? How big is "very big" -- is it not possible to read the entire file into a basic 2-dimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited to allow for the Moving Target.)

The following works on your (*very* limited!) sample data set. It works like this:

1. Load the data set into memory and store it in a simple structure.
2. For every row/col data item, find the required next items: (row,col>=1), (row>=1,col), and (row>=1,col>=1). Untested (because of Lack Of Data), but it *should* use the nearest value.
3. If all four data points are known, interpolate from left to right and top to bottom.

Because your sample data set is so small, it's hard to suggest optimizations. If the distance between successive rows and columns is unknown (the data is in random order, as in your sample), best is to try and read the entire file into memory.

If your data is pre-sorted per *row*, you can suffice with reading one row at the start and then for each loop, read a next row. If, additionally, the data is also sorted per *column*, you can skip the entire `find_set` routine and immediately call `interpolate` for successive items.

The fluff surrounding all `printf` statements is because your preferred output format is not available with the standard C `printf` formatting specifiers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ITEM    25

struct data_t {
    int row;
    int col;
    int data;
} array[MAX_ITEM];

int n_item = 0;

// interpolate A > B
//             v   v
//             C > D
void interpolate (int A, int B, int C, int D)
{
    int i,j, deltaCol,deltaRow;
    float a,b, delta_AC, delta_BD, value;

    a = array[A].data;
    b = array[B].data;

    deltaCol = 2*(array[B].col-array[A].col);
    deltaRow = 5*(array[C].row-array[A].row);

    delta_AC = (array[C].data-array[A].data)/(float)deltaRow;
    delta_BD = (array[D].data-array[B].data)/(float)deltaRow;

    // rows
    for (j=0; j<=deltaRow; j++)
    {
        // columns
        for (i=0; i<=deltaCol; i++)
        {
            if (j % 5)
                printf ("%.1f ", array[A].row+(j/5.0f));
            else
                printf ("%d ", array[A].row+j/5);
            if (i % 2)
                printf ("%.1f ", array[A].col+(i/2.0f));
            else
                printf ("%d ", array[A].col+i/2);

            value = a+(b-a)*((float)i/deltaCol);
            if ((int)(100*value+0.5) % 100)
                printf ("%.1f\n", value);
            else
                printf ("%d\n", (int)(value+0.5f));

        }
        a += delta_AC;
        b += delta_BD;
    }
}

// For a start row/col A find B,C,D
// where B = A(0,>=1), C=A(>=1,0), D=A(>=1,>=1)
void interpolate_from (int A)
{
    int i, B=-1, C=-1, D=-1;

    for (i=0; i<n_item; i++)
    {
        if (i == A) continue;
        if (array[A].row == array[i].row)
        {
            if (array[A].col < array[i].col || (B != -1 && array[i].col < array[B].col))
            {
                B = i;
            }
        } else
        if (array[A].row < array[i].row)
        {
            if (array[A].col == array[i].col)
            {
                C = i;
            } else
            {
                if (array[A].col < array[i].col || (D != -1 && array[i].col < array[D].col))
                {
                    D = i;
                }
            }
        }
        if (B+1 && C+1 && D+1)
        {
            interpolate (A,B,C,D);
            return;
        }
    }

}

int main (void)
{
    int i,j,k;
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen ("data.txt", "r");
    while (n_item < MAX_ITEM && fscanf (f, "%d %d %d", &i,&j, &k) == 3)
    {
        array[n_item].row = i;
        array[n_item].col = j;
        array[n_item].data = k;
        n_item++;
    }
    fclose (f);

    for (i=0; i<n_item; i++)
        interpolate_from (i);

    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

With the amended data set

```
20 14 91
21 14 162
21 18 95
20 18 210
```

the output is:

```
20 14 91
20 14.5 105.9
20 15 120.8
20 15.5 135.6
...
```

(etc. -- run to see the results)

Comment: Explanation: It's a pretty simple bi-linear interpolation, from row to row and column to column. Draw your numbers on a piece of paper and derive manually what the increment per row should be. Then, using those numbers, interpolate column-wise from left to right. The amended program works on both your original data set and your new one -- but note, the numbers should still form a square.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a job for `sort -k1 -k2 -g data.txt`.

Comment: My question is clear I am looking for bilinear interpolation not `sort`

Comment: @Peter My apologies, I thought you had the full data set, just out of order.  In any event, you'll want to sort before you start; then you can fill in the gaps with a program. Since you weren't consistent with which numbers you wanted filled in, I don't know which ones you want; but you'll be able to process it in one pass I would think.

Comment: Its alright, thanks for response